# How to make a sandwich bread with a very soft crust? And what is the ideal temperature to bake sandwich bread?

Tags: baking, bread

I have to ask this question as I really tried hard to achieve a soft crust for sandwich bread but couldn't succeed. I have tried lots of techniques and different recipes but I really couldn't make a bread having a very soft crust that we get in supermarkets. And many recipes say to bake the sandwich bread at 200 degrees C and many other say 180 degrees C, but what is the ideal temperature to bake a sandwich bread with really soft crust? I know that crusty bread is good but many people, especially children don't like to have a crusty sandwich bread!

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9316/67

Answer (score 11):

Use a Pullman loaf pan (aka Pain de Mie pan). You'll also get a square loaf great for sandwiches. Grilled cheese, anyone?

The lid inhibits a "crusty" crust on all sides, just like a regular loaf pan does on all sides but the top.

[image: Pullman]

[image: Pullman2]

I use my 9" Pullman all the time. These are my two favorite, foolproof Pain de Mie recipes.

[Honey Oat](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/honey-oat-pain-de-mie-recipe)

[White](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/a-smaller-pain-de-mie-recipe)

I don't know that it's always the right temperature for soft crusts, but for those loaves, I always use 350F (175C).

Answer (score 8):

The ideal temperature is going to vary depending on your specific formula, the size of your loaves, and so on, so I cannot comment on that.

To encourage a soft crust:

- Use a formula that is enriched with milk or butter for a softer crumb, as well as a softer crust
- Use a loaf pan, as only the top crust will get the extra development from being exposed directly to the air of the oven, which allows it to more easily dry out
- Don't use steam in the oven to encourage crust development
- Don't brush the top of the loaf before baking with anything *or* brush with milk or cream
- Do brush the top of the loaf after baking with melted butter

Comment: One more to add: Once its mostly cool, put it in a plastic bag. Store in the plastic bag. That'll make almost any crust soft.

Comment: Brushing with milk actually makes the crust softer.

Comment: So should I brush with the milk in the beginning or after baking?

Comment: @ChandanSoni brush it just before you put it in the oven

Comment: These comments should be edited into the post itself, especially yours @derobert.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Indeed it should, but as SAJ14SAJ is quite active, I leave it up to him if he'd like to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the best success getting a soft crust by setting the bread on a cooling rack, spreading a little margarine (I just use the end of a stick rubbed into the bread), and then draping a damp cheesecloth over the bread while it cools.  Then I slice and bag the bread - works quite well and we are in high, dry Colorado!

Answer (score 1):

I put a dry towel over my loaves as soon as I take them out of the oven and remove them from the pan (I put them on a cooling rack). Leave the towel on the loaves for a minimum of 10 minutes. This works well for me, even on the odd times when I over bake the loaf.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience covering loaves with a dry (never tried wet) cloth while they cool results in a soft crust. I never glaze the loaves either pre or post baking.