# Substituting honey for sugar in bread

Tags: substitutions, bread, sugar, honey

I want to make one of my favorite white bread sandwich loaves, but I'm out of sugar. What I do have is honey. How much honey should I use to replace 3 Tbs of granulated sugar? How much should I reduce the water in the recipe to compensate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never tried this in baking before, so I did some poking around.  Here are a couple of the more helpful articles:

[SUBSTITUTING HONEY FOR SUGAR](http://www.cooks.com/recipe/4516i4d5/substituting-honey-for-sugar.html)

[Ask the Experts...About Baking with Honey](http://www.homebaking.org/foreducators/askexperts/bakinghoney.html)

These and others seem to agree on a couple major points:

1. For larger quantities (not applicable here) you'll want to add only about 3/4 the volume of honey in place of sugar.  You'll also need to reduce the water in the recipe to compensate.
2. Lower the baking temp by about 25 degrees; honey seems to accelerate browning.
3. Add a very small amount of baking soda (1/4 tsp per cup of honey) to compensate for the honey's natural acidity.

Since you have such a small amount, probably only #2 applies here, but you may want to exercise some caution if making a larger batch.

Comment: I did the same poking around and saw the same things. Point 1 is interesting, because honey *weighs* more than the same volume of sugar. 50% more, to be exact. So, if you measure by weight, you're going to end up with same weight, but 3/4 of volume by using honey. I bake by weight anyway. I imagine the articles say to use less honey for *larger* amounts just for convenience, honey is a pain to measure volumetricly, I don't think anyone has ever used a spoon and accurately measured honey :)

Comment: Point 2 probably doesn't apply for this particular loaf, because I use a [Pullman/Pain de Mie pan](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37082/how-to-make-a-sandwich-bread-with-a-very-soft-crust-and-what-is-the-ideal-tempe/37092#37092) anyway, but it's good to know for other applications.

Comment: I agree that point 3 is probably totally unnecessary for such a small amount. I use honey in other bread recipes and they never call for soda. Again, it's good to know for other applications.

Comment: @Jolenealaska For volumetric measurement no matter the stickiness, google "Metric Wonder Cup".  Absolutely amazing, works with anything you throw at (in?) it.

Comment: Yeah, I've got one. I hardly ever use it though, I usually prefer using the scale. Since I don't have all weights memorized, the plunger style measuring devices work well too. I think I last used mine for peanut butter.

Answer (score 3):

If it's real honey, not adulterated with corn syrup or anything, then you can probably substitute it 1:1 for sugar- I usually do so with my go-to white bread recipe. It does change the flavor somewhat, but it's an improvement in my taste.

Answer (score 1):

I bake breads that are usually a 50/50 mix of unbleached bread flour and spelt, rye, oat or kamut whole grain flours. I may have to adjust the whole grain flour amounts (especially kamut) and add gluten, but I always use honey in place of sugar on a 1:1 basis. I never reduce the temperature. The same 1:1 substitution applies on the occasions that I do make white bread. I have never noticed a change in rise or color. Bread-making is a weekly or bi-weekly event at our house.