# Uses for dry bread

Tags: bread, storage-lifetime

Currently I have a lot of bread. It's not bad, only dry because it's a bit old. I don't want to throw it out. What can I do with it?

Comment: This is a somewhat general question more suited to a traditional forum than here. There is no one right answer to your question, and any answer would be purely subjective.

Comment: See faq:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines  This question is considered

Comment: Also, I don't ask for recipes, just for ways to use an ingredient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uses for stale bread?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/uses-for-stale-bread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I have some very dry leftover bread I run it through the blender and make it into breadcrumbs, whose [uses are legion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_crumbs). In particular, I find that they are a necessary component of frittata and meatballs. After blending, sift the crumbs to remove the bigger chunks and store in an airtight container. Discard if it becomes moldy, but if you store it properly it will keep for weeks.

If the bread is not **very** dry (let's say that you can still cut it without it turning into a cloud of crumbs), you can make bruschetta: lightly toast it, rub garlic on the cut surface with a heavy hand, add olive oil and a sprinkling of salt. Yummy, not so good for your social life.

Old bread is also the basis of the [panzanella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzanella) salad and of bread soups like [panada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panada), [ribollita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribollita) and [pappa al pomodoro](http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2010/aug/29/nigel-slater-pappa-al-pomodoro-classic-recipe). Yes, the Tuscans do love their bread.

Not-too-dry bread can also be cut into little cubes that you can dry in the oven (the microwave also works, but be careful lest you set them on fire) to make *croutons*, the best friends of boring vegetable soups.

Oh, I realized that there is a [canonical entry on the many uses of stale bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/uses-for-stale-bread),

Comment: Panzanella doesn't look hard, so maybe I'm gonna try to make that. I know croutons too, however I don't eat soup often since I'm living in a hostel. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I don't see what living in a hostel has to do with not eating soup! Dry bread can make acceptable toast. The classic British use for stale bread is bread and butter pudding (butter the bread, cut into cubes, layer with some raisins, pour on a mixture of hot milk, sugar and eggs, bake).

Comment: Of course I'd be able to make and eat soup. I'm just too lazy to do that! =D